# `unsigned long long` too small to represent number?

Tags: c++

I have been trying to get the answer to Problem 3 for Project Euler, where I need to find the largest prime factor of 600851475143, but my program gets hung up on this number, not smaller ones (or sometimes bigger ones). I remove the program's more general purpose of finding prime factorization in hopes that it would decrease computation time and perhaps give me an answer, but it did not. Before, when the program started at 1 rather than the input, it gave me the lowest prime, 17, but nothing more. Now it gives me nothing.

For others, what seemed to work was increasing the size of the data type and appending 'ULL' to the end of the variable. This hasn't worked for me. Others suggested creating a big number class, but I am not knowledgeable enough to do that yet, or to work with classes at all, really. Here is the program.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool is_prime(unsigned long long int input);
void factor_number(unsigned long long int input);

int main()
{
    unsigned long long int input = 600851475143ULL;

    cout << "Hello World!\n\n";

    if (is_prime(input) == false)
        factor_number(input);
    else
        cout << input << 1;

    cin.get();

    return 0;
}

bool is_prime(unsigned long long int input)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
    {
        if (i != 1 && i != input)
        {
            if (input % i == 0)
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        else if (i == input)
            return true;
    }
}

void factor_number(unsigned long long int input)
{
    unsigned long long int i = input;

    while (input % i != 0 || is_prime(i) == false)
    {
        i--;
    }
    cout << i << endl;
}
```

Comment: https://mattmccutchen.net/bigint/

Comment: On my implementation (GCC for x86_64) `unsigned long long` can hold values up to 18446744073709551615, so 600851475143 should fit in comfortably.  You can find out the limit of your implementation via [`std::numeric_limits`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/numeric_limits/max).

Comment: Comparing `int` vs `unsigned long long` can be a bad idea. Since this program is exploring the upper bounds of the data type's capacities, this is a very bad idea. The positive numbers you can stuff in int is by nature less than an unsigned int, and very likely far, far less then in an unsigned long long. You won't lose much by making all of the types match.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
bool is_prime(unsigned long long int input)
{
    for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
```

`unsigned long long int` `input` can store a value [0,2^64).

`int` `i` can store a value between [-(2^31),2^31).

When `i` is `2,147,483,647` and you increment it, it becomes negative, so the loop condition, `i <= input` can never be false when `input` is >= 2^31. If `i` was an `unsigned int`, the problem would occur for values >= 2^32.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdint>
#include <limits>

int main() {
    int i = std::numeric_limits<int>::max();
    std::cout << i << "\n";
    ++i;
    std::cout << i << "\n";
}
```

Live demo:http://ideone.com/kmeXti

Chances are, your compiler is giving you a warning when when you compare `i` and `input`, but you've chosen to ignore it.

You can fix your code this way:

```
#include <cstdint>

bool is_prime(uint64_t input)
{
    for (uint64t_t i = 1; i <= input; ++i) {
```

--- EDIT ---

Your prime function also does this:

```
for (int i = 1; i <= input; i++)
{
    if (i != 1 && i != input)
    {
```

Testing conditions inside a loop can be expensive (as in this case where you do the test for every iteration of the loop). If you are worried about the performance of your code, the first thing you should do is try to eliminate these tests.

The loop contains a test for `i != input` - so lets hoist that into the loop condition:

```
for (uint64_t i = 1; i < input; i++)
{
    ...
}
return true;
```

Now we don't need to test for `i != input` inside the loop, but we've still got that pesky 1 to test. We could add some explicit tests at the start:

```
if (input < 4) {
    return (input > 1); // 2 and 3 are prime, 0 and 1 are not
}
```

But more importantly, we can eliminate all the even numbers up-front quickly. If the lowest bit of the number is '0' then the number is even:

```
if ((input & 1) == 0) // even number
    return false;
```

But now we know the number can't be even, we can also do less division tests. Putting it all together:

```
#include <iostream>

bool is_prime(uint64_t input)
{
    if (input < 4)
    {
        // eliminate 1, 2 and 3.
        return (input > 1);
    }
    // Eliminate even numbers
    if ((input & 1) == 0)
        return false;
    // we've eliminated even numbers, so the smallest
    // possible divisor is 3, start from there, but
    // we can also skip all even divisors!
    for (uint64_t div = 3; div <= input / 3; div += 2)
    {
        if ((input % div) == 0)
            return false;
    }
    return true;
}

int main()
{
    for (uint64_t i = 0; i < 64; ++i)
    {
        std::cout << i << ": " << (is_prime(i) ? "yes" : "no") << '\n';
    }
}
```

http://ideone.com/aJqApL

Comment: Bryan can fix that particular problem that way, but the problems with his approach run much deeper than that...

Comment: Agreed, I wasn't sure whether to launch into a "here's how to fix your prime number" implementation when he's clearly just doing early experimentation.

Comment: See --EDIT-- for a more thorough is_prime solution